# Get reputation back on undeleting post

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

I got my post deleted and lost 15 reputation for providing just a link in my answer, why is it that I don't get my reputation back once I undelete my post?

Comment: Which post are we talking about?

Comment: @BilltheLizard [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13917770/1006989)

Comment: Was this maybe just a caching issue?  I see the +15 in your reputation timeline for this now.

Comment: @BilltheLizard don't think so, my answer got accepted and upvoted, still +15 missing

Comment: @X.Jacobs: I see the +15 in on your rep tab right now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, +15 for getting my answer accepted... the same answer that was once deleted

Comment: @X.Jacobs: So, you never lost the rep now. What else is wrong then? If you still fear you lost 15 points and the tally is not correct, check that nothing else was deleted in the meantime, and head to http;//stackoverflow.com/reputation and hit the 'reputation recalc' button at the bottom of that page. If anything *is* skewed, that will right it. If you still don't see any change, then you must've miscalculated somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have -15: got deleted - 15; got upvoted + 10; got accepted + 15; got undeleted ???

Comment: Are you saying you lost `-15` *twice*? You probably misunderstand something. Screenshot?

Comment: no no, just once :)

Comment: checked http;//stackoverflow.com/reputation, can't see -15 anywhere, either in my reputation tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An accept +15 followed by a -15 *in the same day* is a vote and reversal, they are cancelled out and not presented in the reputation view to avoid noise issues from someone spamming the vote buttons.

Comment: the problem is that I did not get my rep back... i had 643, got notified by stackapplet of -15 = 628, edit post, undelete, get upvoted + 10 = 638, get accepted as answer + 15 = 653... i should have 668!

Comment: Your reputation is correct, what you're not taking into account is that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914750/geolocation-api-to-get-lat-long/13914802#13914802) was *also* unaccepted.